# Open PDF created with Webform2PDF in a new browser tab

Tags: 7, webforms, files

I have installed the Webform2PDF module and the PDF is created and can be found under the Results tab.

However, I would really need to open the created PDF in a new tab on submission. How can I do that?

I have tried to use hook_form_alter... but I can't figure out quite how to do it. Any suggestion are welcome.

```
  if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_id'){
    // how to open created PDF after submission
  }
```

Comment: Opening a tab is a client-side operation, you'll need to do it in JavaScript. Bear in mind that the majority of, in fact probably all, modern browsers will warn the user that the site is trying to open a popup unless they've explicitly clicked a link or button to perform the operation

Comment: Ahh, yes of course... Thanks for that. Now I only need to figure out where to find the submission number (second # in the link) and visit a page like this on the client side: http://www.example.com/node/#/submission/#/downloadpdf